# Django Treebeard display tree category using bootstrap effectively

Tags: sql, django, django-treebeard

How to traverse a tree of MP_Node (django-treebeard) categories and display effectively with lease amount of queries? I tried looking the docs but I see the queries number increasing with more categories.

1. Is there a method to limit the number of queries to display a menu like amazon.com and get all the categories in an optimized manner?
2. I see that dump_bulk() api in treebeard gets all the categories in a single query. Is it advisable to use it? If not why? Where is its practical usage?
3. A sample code using twitter-bootstrap nav menu would be appreciated.

I'm looking to reduce the number of queries. Answer with explanation with least number of queries will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose django-mptt in lieu of Treebeard. It's much more simple, and uses only one tree management methodology (MPTT, hence the name). See [this function](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py#L225) (disclaimer, I submitted a patch which rewrote this function to be more optimized) - it caches an entire tree below a given node, allowing you to go up and down the tree as much as you want (e.g., `node.get_children()`, `node.parent`, etc.), without running any more queries. In other words, it's ideal for doing exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Fantastic. You are awesome! :)